# Как загрузить angular 2 проект на хостинг?

Tags: angular2, vps, hosting

Вобшем хочу поставить проект на хостинг. но когда обратился в тех поддержку мне сказали что виртуальный хостинг не подходит для Angular 2. и нужно покупать VPS. Вопрос, можно ли как-нибудь поставить на виртуальный хостинг или об'язательно нужен VPS?

Comment: Зависит от хостинга. Если этот конкретный вам сказал, что не может, то скорее всего, он прав. А на VPS разместить можно приблизительно что угодно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если у вас веб проект который общается с back-end частью через API достаточно собрать проект и выложить на сервер, например IIS.

1) В **main.ts**

```
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
**enableProdMode();**
bootstrap(....);
```

2) Собираем проект в production mode :
 **ng build --prod**

3) После сборки, angular-cli создаст папку **dist**. Она содержит HTML, JS, Assets и прочее

4) Размещаем на любом веб сервере, как статический ресурс. Достаточно того чтобы сервер смотрел на index.html

для IIS веб конфиг будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <add value="views/index.html" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все получилось

Comment: Рад что помог, тогда выбери ответ как верный, может другим тоже будет полезно